# Where to ask question about software design process / tools?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

We are working on a C/C++ API for an application with a distributed team which is located all over the world. I am looking for feedback suggestions how to organize a collaborative API design effort and also which tools can be used to support this effort.

What would be the correct community for questions like this?

Comment: [programmers.se] maybe? Although, take a look at their tour for their guidelines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmers is the best fit for what you need, however as your question is now you will get vote close for those reasons :

- Tools recommendation are off-topic.
- If not bordered and explained well, how to organize a collaborative API design will fall on the Too broad category and Primarily opinion based. This is because SE sites are in the format of Q&A and a so general question just won't fit.

What you can do to not fall under the close flags :

- Split your problem in set of focused questions.
- Find some existing tools / method by googling to a part of your current (very wide) problem, think about how you may use it, and asked for flaws in your approach.

About tools questions, you should read this on programmer's meta : https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go?cb=1.

If you have some rep on programmers, you can go to their chat to in order to get help on things that are on-topic be just won't fit for a question.